# Qt: How to set a date with time, to a QDateTimeEdit?

Tags: qt, datetime, format

I'm getting dates formatted like this: "2011-04-14 15:00:00", and want to set them to a QDateTimeEdit object.

This is what i do:

```
void MainWindow::setUIDateAndTime(QString &date)
{
    QDateTime dateTime;
    dateTime.fromString(date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    QString sDatetime = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); // For debug testing

    // Create the datetime picker
    QDateTimeEdit *dateTimePicker = new QDateTimeEdit(dateTime);
    dateTimePicker->setObjectName("dateTimePicker");

    ui->frameCommentHolderLayout->addWidget(dateTimePicker);
}
```

But it never get's set.
The debug variable "sDateTime" is always set to "".

Does Anybody see what i do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[fromString](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdatetime.html#fromString-2) function is `static` in QDateTime class. That means it *doesn't* modify state of your `dateTime` object. Try this:

```
QDateTime dateTime(QDateTime::fromString(date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Yes, this works, you can also put it as `dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(.....);`

Comment: Try to check with `isValid` function member returnd QDateTime. Seems you have some troubles with your `date` string. Have you checked it before use?

Comment: Suggestion to how i can debug the dateTime object? If i use the Qt debugger i only get "<not available>" if i try to explore the object.

Comment: Here is a working example: http://codepaste.appspot.com/show?id=506124
It takes date strings as command arguments. You'll need to quote the embedded space otherwise it will be treated as two arguments, each not conforming to the specified format.

Comment: @Tilman Vogel: hmmm, does this mean, that something is wrong with `QDateTime dateTime=(QDateTime::fromString(/*...*/))` compare to 'QDateTime = QDateTime::fromString(/**/)'? I always think they are identical, except that in first case you save yourself an assignment operator (in second case compiler can save it for you).

Comment: @ikky: just print it using `qdebug` for example.

Comment: @beduin: haha, i must have slipped while testing your code... somehow the date argument was removed by me, but no compiler error.... it's now working :) Thanks!

Comment: @Ikky, you should really read the documentation: `QDateTime::fromString()` with a single `QString` argument gets parsed according to `Qt::TextDate` which is basically `ddd MMM d yyyy` with localized short names and seemingly no fields for the time.